# Empty page on the Part page

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, fancyhdr, etoolbox, parts

I'm using this on my document (scrartcl documentclass):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\section}{\cleardoubleevenemptypage}{}{}
\pretocmd{\part}{\cleardoubleevenemptypage}{}{}
```

This makes me get blank pages so that the sections and parts always start on even pages, which is nice. (I shall say I'm using fancyhdr to define the header and footer).

So my question, is there any similar command to `\pretocmd` that applies to the current section page instead of the previous pages? I've looked for such thing in the `etoolbox` documentation, but I couldn't find anything.

**More precisely, what I want is to get no header and footer on the *Part* pages.**

Edit: I know I can use `\part{}\thispagestyle{empty}` but I'd like to make this step automatic by defining it (similar to the `\pretocmd` command) within the the document preamble.

Comment: What happens if you use `\part{title}\thispagestyle{empty}`?

Comment: @Sigur Oh, yes, it works. But is there a way to define it into the document preamble? It's not a big deal to do it manually on every part, but I'd like to make it automatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your preamble to use the following:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\pretocmd{\section}{\cleardoubleevenemptypage}{}{}
\pretocmd{\part}{\cleardoubleevenemptypage\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
```

This will, after clearing the page to start on an even page, immediately issue `\thispagestyle{empty}`. It is equivalent to performing

```
\part{<part title>}\thispagestyle{empty}
```

manually. Here's a mild illustration (doesn't use [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr), although the principle is the same):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/KOMA-script
\usepackage{etoolbox,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{etoolbox,lipsum}
\pretocmd{\section}{\cleardoubleevenemptypage}{}{}
\pretocmd{\part}{\cleardoubleevenemptypage\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
\begin{document}
\part{A part}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-12]
\part{Another part}
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[13-25]
\part{A final part}
\section{A final section}
\lipsum[13-25]
\end{document}
```